# My iMac detects a samsung external monitor, but nothing comes up on the display

Tags: display, imac, hdmi

I've got a late 2013 iMac running OS X El Capitan and am trying to get a second screen for work. Its a Samsung LED Syncmaster SA350 Series (Plug & Play). When I plug it in, nothing but a black screen displays, even though its on and my Mac detects it (I can even drag windows over there etc). I'm connecting DVI-->HDMI.

Most of the answers I've found on this say to update the firmware, but It doesn't look like I can do that on my Mac. Is there any way to get this screen to start displaying other than through a firmware update?

Thanks!

Comment: Just asking, but is the brightness turned up all the way?

Comment: I do have the brightness up. I guess I should add that when disconnected from my mac, I get a bouncing box with RGB in it that says "check signal cable". So apart, it seems to work fine, but once plugged in, something is lost in translation

Comment: Just to be sure, are you selecting the correct input source on the monitor?

Comment: Have you checked under "Display" in System Preferences and selected "Mirror Displays" under the "Arrangement" tab? I have a black screen as my desktop background so that confused me a while back because the default for plugging in a display is "extend" and not "mirror".

Comment: When I open displays, I can see and arrange the second screen over. I can even drag items off my main screen and onto where the second one should be, but it just doesn't show up on the second one. I actually lost a window over there this morning trying to test it out.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Have you tried plugging the monitor in to another computer as the *only* monitor? Like a Mac mini or a Windows PC?